# Changing color for treemap in tmPlot in R

Tags: r, treemap

How can i create treemap with only two colors(red(-ve) and green(+ve)) exactly. I am currently using tmPlot and here follows my sample data and sample code.

```
index vSize vColor
S1    100    1
S2    150   -1
S3    125    1
S4    267   -1 

     svg("sample.svg")
     library(treemap)
     tmPlot(data,c("index"),"vSize","vColor","comp")
     dev.off()
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do you actually want two fixed colors, i.e. two categories, or do you still want the numeric scale?

In the first case, the code is:

```
library(treemap)
data <- data.frame(index=paste0("S",1:4), vSize=c(100,150,125,267),
                   vColor=factor(c(1,-1,1,-1)))
treemap(data,c("index"), "vSize", "vColor", "categorical")
```

For this 'categorical' treemap I factorized the vColor variable. You can assign any fixed colors you like with the argument palette.

Best,
Martijn

Comment: Hi MTennekes, I am very thankful for your response. I need a bit clarification here. Can you kindly provide me the same with tmPlot() instead of treemap(), since I am using R 2.15.3 I am not able to use treemap().

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Sivs, it should work the same with tmPlot() in older versions. If not, could me give me the error/warning messages?